# fatal error: 'Eigen/Core' file not found

Tags: python, eigen

Well... I have tried the opensource project(https://github.com/seanbell/intrinsic) several weeks...
But when I make this file, then it show the error.
I have installed the eigen, opencv, numpy. The error still happene

```
python setup.py build_ext -i
Warning: Extension name 'krahenbuhl2013' does not match fully qualified name 'bell2014.krahenbuhl2013.krahenbuhl2013' of 'krahenbuhl2013.pyx'
running build_ext
building 'krahenbuhl2013' extension
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Users/Chen/anaconda2/include -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -Iinclude -I/usr/include/eigen3 -I/Users/Chen/anaconda2/include/python2.7 -c krahenbuhl2013.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/krahenbuhl2013.o

In file included from krahenbuhl2013.cpp:569:
In file included from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4:
In file included from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18:
In file included from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1816:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: 
      "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by "          "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API
      NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
#warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
 ^
In file included from krahenbuhl2013.cpp:571:
In file included from ./include/densecrf_wrapper.h:1:
In file included from include/densecrf.h:29:
include/unary.h:28:10: fatal error: 'Eigen/Core' file not found
#include <Eigen/Core>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Comment: From the github readme: "If you are on another operating system or eigen3 is in another directory, edit krahenbuhl2013/setup.py to change the directory." So, how did you edit setup.py? What OS are you on? Where is Eigen installed?

Comment: I fix the problem.
I use mac to program this project.
The error I have is cannot find the file "Eigen/Core", and then I go through every code and change the path from "Eigen/Core" to "eigen3/Eigen/Core".
After that, it works.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem by recoding the code.
In the path
    /krahenbuhl2013/include/
every code has "`Eigen/Core`", change into "`eigen3/Eigen/Core`".
After that, it works.

Comment: That does not sound like a good solution. Did you read/try @AviGinsburg's suggestion to edit `setup.py` instead?

Comment: @chtz I put my setup.py below, you can see the code...and i am not sure do i need to edit it or not